# Query string like parameters regex

Tags: php, regex

From a text like:

```
category=[123,456,789], subcategories, id=579, not_in_category=[111,333]
```

I need a regex to get something like:

```
$params[category][0] = 123;
$params[category][1] = 456;
$params[category][2] = 789;
$params[subcategories] = ; // I just need to know that this exists
$params[id] = 579;
$params[not_category][0] = 111;
$params[not_category][1] = 333;
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

PS

As you suggested, I clarify that the structure and the number of items may change.
Basically the structure is:

```
key=value, key=value, key=value, ...
```

where value can be:

- a single value (e.g. `category=123` or `postID=123` or `mykey=myvalue`, ...)
- an "array" (e.g. `category=[123,456,789]`)
- a "boolean" where the TRUE value is an assumption from the fact that "key" exists in the array (e.g. `subcategories`)

Comment: where did you get this text?

Comment: it's the params block of a template engine:
{block:Posts category=[123,456,789], subcategories, id=579, not_in_category=[111,333]}

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @AldoB Do you need that `$params` array, or do you just need to know if `subcategories` is in the list?

Comment: Lots of attempts, but nothing seems to work..

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I need $params as described. To know if subcategories exists I think that having it in the array is enough, right?

Comment: @AldoB So you want that `$params` array (it's not just for "subcategories")? i.e. there are two parts to this question, turning that string into an array, then testing if subcategories is there

Comment: @AldoB See if my answer below does what you're after

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Yes it does, thanks! I thought that everything should be done with only a regex.. would it be more complicated or more "heavy"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35272/discussion-between-aldob-and-smokeyphp)

Comment: @AldoB If you mean get the same end result with a single regex, that's more impossible than just heavy! Also, if this has helped you resolve your problem, please consider clicking the green tick under the vote arrows to let other visitors know what your solution was

Comment: Don't tell us about your "lots of attempts".  Show them to us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method should be flexible enough:

```
$str = 'category=[123,456,789], subcategories, id=579, not_in_category=[111,333]';
$str = preg_replace('#,([^0-9 ])#',', $1',$str); //fix for string format with no spaces (count=10,paginate,body_length=300)
preg_match_all('#(.+?)(,[^0-9]|$)#',$str,$sections); //get each section
$params = array();
foreach($sections[1] as $param)
{
    list($key,$val) = explode('=',$param); //Put either side of the "=" into variables $key and $val
    if(!is_null($val) && preg_match('#\[([0-9,]+)\]#',$val,$match)>0)
    {
        $val = explode(',',$match[1]); //turn the comma separated numbers into an array
    }
    $params[$key] = is_null($val) ? '' : $val;//Use blank string instead of NULL
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($params,true).'</pre>';
var_dump(isset($params['subcategories']));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
            [2] => 789
        )

    [subcategories] => 
    [id] => 579
    [not_in_category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 333
        )

)

bool(true)
```

Alternate (no string manipulation before process):

```
$str = 'count=10,paginate,body_length=300,rawr=[1,2,3]';
preg_match_all('#(.+?)(,([^0-9,])|$)#',$str,$sections); //get each section
$params = array();
foreach($sections[1] as $k => $param)
{
    list($key,$val) = explode('=',$param); //Put either side of the "=" into variables $key and $val
    $key = isset($sections[3][$k-1]) ? trim($sections[3][$k-1]).$key : $key; //Fetch first character stolen by previous match
    if(!is_null($val) && preg_match('#\[([0-9,]+)\]#',$val,$match)>0)
    {
        $val = explode(',',$match[1]); //turn the comma separated numbers into an array
    }
    $params[$key] = is_null($val) ? '' : $val;//Use blank string instead of NULL
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($params,true).'</pre>';
```

*Another* alternate: full re-format of string before process for safety

```
$str = 'count=10,paginate,body_length=300,rawr=[1, 2,3] , name = mike';
$str = preg_replace(array('#\s+#','#,([^0-9 ])#'),array('',', $1'),$str); //fix for varying string formats
preg_match_all('#(.+?)(,[^0-9]|$)#',$str,$sections); //get each section
$params = array();
foreach($sections[1] as $param)
{
    list($key,$val) = explode('=',$param); //Put either side of the "=" into variables $key and $val
    if(!is_null($val) && preg_match('#\[([0-9,]+)\]#',$val,$match)>0)
    {
        $val = explode(',',$match[1]); //turn the comma separated numbers into an array
    }
    $params[$key] = is_null($val) ? '' : $val;//Use blank string instead of NULL
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($params,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: I was testing out the `explode` myself when I refreshed the page... you got there earlier! :) GJ!

Comment: This solution won't work with a text like this:
`count=10,paginate,body_length=300` maybe because of the comma right close to param key..

Comment: @AldoB You can run `$str = preg_replace('#,([^0-9 ])#',', $1',$str);` before the process to add spaces after the commas

Comment: @AldoB I have another fix if you'd rather not change the string before running the process. Let me know if you want it

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I tried to use your last update, but for a string like `$str = 'count=10,paginate,body_length=300,rawr=[1,   2,3]     ,      name =        mike';` the result is not as expected: 
`Array
(
    [count] => 10
    [paginate] => 
    [body_length] => 300
    [rawr] => [1
    [2,3]] => 
    [name] =>         mike
)`
I'm trying to edit the code, starting from yours will be easier.. thanks..!

Comment: @AldoB Why do you have so many different versions - why is the input text not standardised, where is it coming from?

Comment: @AldoB Check my answer - I've updated it again. At the end, it now fully reformats the string, making all strings provided thus far work as expected.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Great! Thanks
The format can vary because that string is generated by the user, so I'd like to be sure that it works even if the user "mistype" the string..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON also, it's native in PHP : http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.json.php

It will be more easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$subject = "category=[123,456,789], subcategories, id=579, not_in_category=[111,333]";
$pattern = '/category=\[(.*?)\,(.*?)\,(.*?)\]\,\s(subcategories),\sid=(.*?)\,\snot_in_category=\[(.*?)\,(.*?)\]/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

I think this will get you the matches out... didn't actually test it but it might be a good starting point.

Then you just need to push the matches to the correct place in the array you need. Also test if the `subcategories` string exists with `strcmp` or something...

Also, notice that I assumed your `subject` string has that fixe dtype of structure... if it is changing often, you'll need much more than this...

Comment: To get the answer you need, you should try to explain what changes in the structure. For instance, if the # of items in the `categories` array varies; if the # of items in the `not_in_category` varies; etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'category=[123,456,789], subcategories, id=579, not_in_category=[111,333]';
$main_arr = preg_split('/(,\s)+/', $str);
$params = array();
foreach( $main_arr as $value) {
    $pos = strpos($value, '=');
    if($pos === false) {
        $params[$value] = null;
    } else {
        $index_part = substr($value, 0, $pos);
        $value_part = substr($value, $pos+1, strlen($value));
        $match = preg_match('/\[(.*?)\]/', $value_part,$xarr);
        if($match) {
            $inner_arr = preg_split('/(,)+/', $xarr[1]);
            foreach($inner_arr as $v) {
                $params[$index_part][] = $v;
            }
        } else {
            $params[$index_part] = $value_part;
        }

    }
}

print_r( $params );
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
            [2] => 789
        )

    [subcategories] => 
    [id] => 579
    [not_in_category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 333
        )

)
```